# error with matching a string with a regular expression

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what I did wrong, my regular expression below is fine:

```
var number = bio.match(\(?(?:\+62|62|0)(?:\d{2,3})?\)?[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4});
console.log(number);
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m
```

Comment: Regex literals are denoted by forward slashes, e.g.: `/[a-z]/`

Comment: regex should be enclosed in `/<regex>/` or [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score -1):

The correct one is:

```
bio.match(\((?:\+62|62|0)?(?:\d{2,3})?\)?[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4});
```